# What is special about "Quantum spatial entanglement"?

Tags: plot-device, salvation

In book 2 of Peter Hamilton's Salvation sequence, there is some talk about elements having tried to subvert the key *portal teleportation technology*, similar to his FTL/wormhole trains in previous books.  Also very close to the gates in Hyperion.

> "Quantum spatial entanglement is not something we have any record of" XXX said.  "That may be to prevent the YYY from acquiring the technology or it may be genuinely unique to your species (humans)".

Thing is, the bad YYY aliens **do** have gate technology,  and XXX specifically warns humans about it in book 1.  And as far as I could tell it operates under the same constraints as the human version.  The human version is entirely based on the popular meme of quantum particle entanglement, the demonstrated real life synchronicity of some aspect of 2 distant particles' quantum attributes.  So what is supposed to be special about humanity's version of that tech?  It's a bit like saying that only humans discovered Bernoulli's lift equations, but many species fly airplanes nevertheless.

Book 1 is a bit of a whodunnit, so I have tried to avoid spoilers with XXX/YYY.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit more speculative than I would like, but it based on physics. I would argue that the wormhole technology of the aliens and the quantum spatial entanglement technology of the humans does a very similar thing (transportation along long distances) using different physical mechanisms.

A wormhole is something that can pop up in General Relativity, while Quantum Spatial Entanglement seems to be a Quantum Mechanics effects, albeit one that I have not heard being speculated about as a possibility. You can see that they behave differently in several ways, for example, the wormhole once not shielded emits gravity waves while there is no similar effect for the QSE gates.

Other different properties are hard to state for certain, but it seems that the Wormhole needs to be continually maintained and kept open while you can open and close the QSE gates as required.